# Deploying multiple Rails applications to DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, nginx, unicorn, digital-ocean

I'm using Digital Ocean droplet for rails application. I've managed to deploy first application with success, but now facing with problems trying to deploy the second one. I am using unicorn as app server and nginx as web server. OS is Ubuntu 14.04

I've read lots of threads on stackexchange sites, also on blogs etc. but none of them fits my position. Problem is, I think, on app and system folder/file/configuration structures. Which I am very cautious to change anything on system configuration files.

In most examples on web, everyone is talking about unicorn.rb inside 
`rails_root/config/` however I don't have any. Instead I have unicorn.conf with same content inside `/etc`.

There is also a socket file which listens for first app, and I tried two create the second for my second app - but it failed.

I know, I have to create another unicorn configuration for second app, and also have to do something which should be resulted with the creation of a socket for second.

But the lack of knowledge and understanding about system administration drives me to trouble.

Can anyone guide me about this problem?

I can provide more files if needed.

nginx configuration file for first app (path `/etc/sites-available/first_app`).

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    root /home/rails/myfirstapp/public;
    server_name www.myfirstapp.com;
    index index.htm index.html index.php index.asp index.aspx index.cgi index.pl index.jsp;

    location / {
            try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
    }


    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
                    try_files $uri @app;
            }

     location @app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.myfirstapp.com;
    return 301 $scheme://myfirstapp.com$request_uri;    
}
```

second app (`/etc/sites-available/second_app`)

```
upstream app_server_2 {
    server unix:/var/run/unicorn.app_two.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    root /home/rails/secondapp/public;
    server_name secondapp.com;
    index index.htm index.html index.php index.asp index.aspx index.cgi index.pl index.jsp;

    location / {
            try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
    }


    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
                    try_files $uri @app;
            }

     location @app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server_2;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name secondapp.com www.secondapp.com;
    return 301 $scheme://secondapp.com$request_uri; 
}
```

(`/etc/unicorn.conf`)

```
listen "unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock"
worker_processes 4
user "rails"
working_directory "/home/rails/myfirstapp"
pid "/var/run/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

This has probably gone unanswered because you should just use 2 independent droplets as opposed to trying to make this work (which will be a bit of a nightmare for those unfamiliar with server and deployment stuff). Rails has lots of ways to interconnect 2 apps across the interwebs.

If you need to share the database you could even just setup a third droplet (although not needed) and host the centralised DB from there and have both apps connected to it. That also sets you up for mucho scalability.

Unless, of course, I misunderstood what you are trying to do.

If you are using 2 droplets and grammar is our fickle mistress, hook us up with some more details man.

Comment: yes, i'm not much familiar with server/deployment stuffs. so, i bought (or whatever is the exact verb for it) second droplet -))